# Using Pandas groupby in user defined function: why I can't use aggregation functions to groupyby

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I defined the following user function:

```
def group_by(df, columns):
    x = df.groupby(columns).sum()
    x = x.reset_index()
    return x
```

It works!

But the following does not! :

```
def group_by(df, columns, aggfunc=sum):
    x = df.groupby(columns).aggfunc()
    x = x.reset_index()
    return x
```

I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'aggfunc'
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing `df.groupby(columns).aggfunc()` you are doing a method call on the [groupby object](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html), this means Python will look for a method called aggfunc on this object. As this method does not exists it throws an AttributeError. The fact that you have aggfunc as an input parameter of your function doesn't affect this process.

You could however use the [.agg()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) method to which you could pass the local variable aggfunc you have defined as input parameter.

```
x = df.groupby(columns).agg(aggfunc)
```

Comment: This definitely solves their problem. I think their problem arises from a misunderstanding of using `sum` as an input in their function, expecting it to be used as the `.sum()` method in the function.

Comment: I agree, I've added additional explanation to the answer.